# Move functionality from a ViewController to another file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scope

Noob here. I have a really long function `sliderChange()` executing upon slider value change which I want to move to it's own Swift controller file `CR_SlilderChangeCalc.swift`. I have variable `myGlobalVar` in the `UIViewController` which I need to access from the new function too. How do I access those variables?

eg View Controller:

```
class MyDodgyViewController: UIViewController {

    // ... some code here

    let myGlobalVar: Float = myCalculatedVar

    @IBAction func sliderChange(_ sender: UISlider){

    sliderChangeCalc(sender: sender)

    }

}
```

eg: CR_SlilderChangeCalc.swift

```
func sliderChangeCalc(sender: UISlider) {

    // doesn't work
    let MyNewVar :Float = MyDodgyViewController.MyGlobalVar 

    // do some cool stuff

}
```

Comment: Show some code of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: by mistake i have posted answer here! deleted it btw!

Comment: added some code-ish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass myGlobalVar as a parameter to your method sliderChangeCalc, i.e.

```
func sliderChangeCalc(sender: UISlider, myGlobalVar: Float)
{

    // do some cool stuff

}
```

Method call:

```
@IBAction func sliderChange(_ sender: UISlider){

    sliderChangeCalc(sender: sender, myGlobalVar: self. myGlobalVar)

    }
```